# Google App Script - how to call a function from a library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code bound to a spreadsheet.
I published a standalone google app script as a library, for which I got an ID.

```
function callActivateNewMember(){
 var scriptId = "<LIBRARY SCRIPT ID>";
 google.script.run({
  'scriptId': scriptId,
  'resource': {
  'function': 'activateNewMember'
 }
})
```

}

I got an error message upon execution:

> ReferenceError: "google" is not defined.

My intention is simply to keep the code of the application using a spreadsheet and limit the code of the spreadsheet to simply call the function from the standalone code.

Comment: `google.script.run` is valid only within the HTML file served via `HtmlService`. Review library documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use libraries you import them from the ResourcesTab and then later you call them with normal dot notation.

Go to Resources > Libraries
Add a library (this is where you use the script id)

Then you should be ready to go.

In the script use the string that is called "Identifier" in the libraries popup.

```
LibraryIdentifier.activateNewMember();
```

You should already be familiar with this idea from logging:

```
Logger.log("Hi There");
```

Comment: Can you point to any coded examples of using a library you created. I have read the developers meager notes.